# Attempting to install NodeJS 14 installs NodeJS 8 instead

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, ubuntu-18.04

I am having trouble installing&running nodejs on my ubuntu 18 pc.

I run following commands step by step:

```
sudo apt update
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt -y install nodejs
```

And later checked the version number:

```
node -v
v8.10.0
```

Later I removed nodejs and i tried to install nodejs 12, 13 and 11, every time it is installing `v8.10.0`.

Can anyone please help me in this case?

Comment: Have you tried to download it and setup?
https://nodejs.org/

Comment: My guess would be that `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo bash -` fails. We probably need the output of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess it's nvm, run

`nvm ls` to list all the node versions

`nvm use <node version you want to use>`

`nvm current` to check the node version in use

Answer (score 1):

My theory is that node 8 is installed no matter what and that it's in your PATH with a higher priority. Try uninstalling all versions of node and run `node -v` to verify that. If that's the case, I suggest you try to find a way to uninstall that version of node before reinstalling the version you want.

Also by typing `which node` you can get the path of the current executable that is being called when you call the `node` command. It may be a symlink in which case `ls -l` of the returned path would show you to path pointed by it.

Anyway, I suggest using `nvm` (Node Version Manager). Documentation at https://nvm.sh